# vue3: how to add a globalProperties which is base on $attr

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In vue3, I try to add attributes like `$attrsWithoutIdClassStyle` and `$attrsIdClassStyleOnly` to the [`globalProperties`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties) which the values are based on the `$attrs` of current vue-component

It can be achieved by the [global `mixins`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mixin)

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from '~/App.vue';

createApp(App)
    mixin({
        computed: {
            $attrsWithoutIdClassStyle() {
                return _.omit(this.$attrs, ['id', 'class', 'style']);
            },
            $attrsIdClassStyleOnly() {
                return _.pick(this.$attrs, ['id', 'class', 'style']);
            },
        }
    })
```

But since the [`mixin` is not recommended in vue3 any more](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-mixin), also the code is ugly.

So, how can I add the custom attributes to the global properties via [`app-config-globalproperties`](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties) which is a dynamic value based on the current vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation suggests, the proper Vue 3 replacement is to use a composable function and import where needed.

composables/myAttrs.js

```
import { useAttrs } from 'vue';
import _ from 'lodash';
export function useMyAttrs() {
  const attrs = useAttrs();
  const attrsWithoutIdClassStyle = _.omit(attrs, ['id', 'class', 'style']);
  const attrsIdClassStyleOnly = _.pick(attrs, ['id', 'class', 'style']);
  return {
    attrsWithoutIdClassStyle,
    attrsIdClassStyleOnly
  };
}
```

in your components,

```
import { useMyAttrs } from '@/composables/myAttrs';
const { attrsWithoutIdClassStyle, attrsIdClassStyleOnly } = useMyAttrs();
```